# Allow user access to Dashboard only!

Tags: users, dashboard, user-access

Update: This snippet below removes the menu also for my admin account:

```
function remove_menu_items() {

    global $menu;
    global $user_ID; 

    if( $user_ID ) :

        /* Dashboard only acccess */
        if( current_user_can( 'Dashboardvisitors' ) ) :

            $restricted = array(
                __('Posts'),
                __('Media'),
                __('Pages'),
                __('Links'),
                __('Appearance'),
                __('Tools'),
                __('Users'),
                __('Settings'),
                __('Comments'),
                __('Plugins')
            );

        endif;

    endif;  

    end ( $menu );

    while ( prev( $menu ) ) :
        $value = explode( ' ', $menu[key($menu)][0] );
        if( in_array( $value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted ) ) :
            unset( $menu[key($menu)] );
        endif;
    endwhile;

}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menu_items');
```

How can I give a user access to the dashboard only?

More specifically, I want them to be able to see the wordpress stats widget and the google analytics widget. That's it.

I've created a new user with the role dashboardvisitors using the plugin USER ROLE EDITOR.

Now **level 0 plus read access** doesn't cut it. The dashboard is just empty.

Adding **edit dashboard** doesn't change anything. Still nothing there (but I don't want them to be able to edit the dashboard anyways).

How can I make this happen? It's very important, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in your `functions.php` :

```
function remove_menu_items() {

    global $menu;
    global $user_ID; 

    if( $user_ID ) :

        /* Dashboard only acccess */
        if( current_user_can( 'dashboardvisitors' ) ) :

                $restricted = array(
                    __('Posts'),
                    __('Pages'),
                    __('Links'), 
                    [etc...]
            );

        endif;

    endif;  

    end ( $menu );

    while ( prev( $menu ) ) :
        $value = explode( ' ', $menu[key($menu)][0] );
        if( in_array( $value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted ) ) :
            unset( $menu[key($menu)] );
        endif;
    endwhile;

}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menu_items');
```

What it does is that for each user of the role 'dashboardvisitors' going to the WP admin, it removes the menu items listed in the `restricted` array. If you list all the admin sections except the dashboard in that array you should have a dashboard only admin.

Comment: Thanks @mike23, where can I find a list of all the arrays that I can/should remove?